# twitter streaming api seems unresponsive

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am using `twython` to capture streams from twitter. Some times it works as expected but some other times it becomes unresponsive for quite some time and then retuns a 420 error code. To be more specific
using this class

```
class TweetStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
def on_success(self, data):
    if 'text' in data:
        print data['text'].encode('utf-8')

def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print status_code
    self.disconnect()
```

I filter a stream using the terms shown bellow

```
tw_stream = TweetStreamer(api_key, api_secret, access, access_secret)
tw_stream.statuses.filter(track=['I', 'a', 'this', 'that', 'the', 'The', 'today'])
```

Can it be a `twython` issue? I haven't actually checked the source code but I believe the requests are handled properly and the problem should be somewhere between authentication and / or the api being unavailable for some reason? Does it make sense to regenerate my keys?

**update**

the error msg I am getting is

> b'Easy there, Turbo. Too many requests recently. Enhance your calm.\r\n'

does this mean that the api is currently receiving too many requests or that I am sending too many requests?

Comment: How often does it return 420, and are you sure you are below the rate limit?

Comment: It's happening (how I see it ) randomly, but it's probably due to me sending too many requests. I thought that the streaming api had no rate limit :/ or at least you didn't have to care about it

Comment: try time.sleep(3) or something like that to make the streamer pause

Comment: @wwl Where do I add the time.sleep(), do we add it inside the TweetStreamer's filter() method?